# How to let bazel recursively download dependencies by maven_jar in java

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-datastore, bazel, maven-jar-plugin

I am new to Bazel and would like to implement a Google Cloud Datastore client in Java. I tried to add the google-cloud-datastore jar as a dependency in my Bazel project. I added the maven_jar workspace rule in my WORKSPACE file as follows:

```
maven_jar(
    name = "google_cloud_datastore",
    artifact = "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:1.97.0",
)
```

I found that Bazel could only download the exact google-cloud-datastore classes without other relevant and reliable dependencies as what Maven project does. Could Bazel recursively find and download dependencies based on maven_jar requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that `maven_jar` does not download any dependencies recursively. You'll want to use [`rules_jvm_external`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external) for this.

Comment: Further, maven_jar is not recommended at this point, if I'm not mistaken.